# What does the component prop of Typography do in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been using  for a while and I've never understood the purpose of the component prop. I've read the documentation and it still doesn't make sense to me. I've also read this [interpretation of the component prop of the typography component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705789/what-are-the-valid-values-for-material-uis-typography-component) but that also doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone ELI5 what this prop does?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding its purpose is standardizing type(text/font) styles and sizes (font size), on the other hand it accepts a `component` prop, which is used as the actual element to render the "text" in. It could be a DOM element or a component. Also there is a `variant` prop which determines the the style (including but not only the text size) of the "text", so the component is independent of the variant, so is the styling.

> The Typography component uses the variantMapping property to associate a UI variant with a semantic element. It’s important to realize that the style of a typography is independent from the semantic underlying element. ~ [Typography](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/)

```
    <Typography variant="h1" component="h2">
             h1. Heading
    </Typography>
```

so the above snippet will render a `<h2/>` element with `<h1/>` element styling.

there is also a way to change variant to DOM element mapping. [Changing the semantic element](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/#changing-the-semantic-element)

Comment: Why would someone want to do this?